# concatenating a new column and renaming it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to generate a new column based on another (hour column from the time column). The problem is that after concatenating, it's getting the same name ("time").
Moreover, when I try to change one, the other changes as well.

Why is that?

Here's the code

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
hour_col = pd.Series(df['time']).copy()
hour_col = hour_col.apply(lambda t: t.hour)
df = pd.concat([df, hour_col], axis=1)
```

Name change:

```
df = df.rename(columns={ df.columns[3]: "hour" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['hours'] = df['time'].dt.hour
```

---

But if really need your solution only `rename` `column`, converting to `Series` is not necessary, because each column of `DataFrame` is `Series` after selecting `(print (type(df['time'])))`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['10:20:30','20:03:04']})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
hour_col = df['time'].rename('hour')
hour_col = hour_col.apply(lambda t: t.hour)
df = pd.concat([df, hour_col], axis=1)
print (df)
                 time  hour
0 2018-11-24 10:20:30    10
1 2018-11-24 20:03:04    20
```

If want replace columns by position (e.g. because duplicated values and `rename` change both names like mentioned @Gla Avineri in comment) use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['10:20:30','20:03:04'],
                   'a':[2,3],
                   'b':[-4,5]})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
hour_col = df['time']
hour_col = hour_col.apply(lambda t: t.hour)
df = pd.concat([df, hour_col], axis=1)

#converting to list because columns are immutable
cols = df.columns.tolist()
#set 4th value
cols[3] = 'hour'
#assign back
df.columns = cols

print (df)
                 time  a  b  hour
0 2018-11-24 10:20:30  2 -4    10
1 2018-11-24 20:03:04  3  5    20
```

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. Out of curiosity, what is the problem with my code? Why is it behaving like that?

Comment: I would guess that in your code, when you copy the *time* series of the dataframe, you are also copying it's name - "time". Than when you concatenate the new series to the dataframe, it appears with the name "time". When you use ```rename```, you ask to rename ```df.columns[3]``` to "hour". But ```df.columns[3]``` holds the value "time", so what you basically wrote there is ```rename(columns={"time": "hour"})```. As i explained earlier your df had 2 columns named "time" up to this point, so now they will both be changed to "hour".

Comment: @GalAvineri - Yes, I agree - Added solution for this.